# Export json data with highcharts

Tags: highcharts

it is possible export `Json` data form highcharts,

It is possible include the option Download like JSON

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What should JSON include? chart options?

Comment: hi @morganfree the same info that I read To form the chart  for example this.. https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?  I want to exporting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define custom items for the exporting menu and attach onclick callback to them.

```
exporting: {
    buttons: {
      contextButton: {
        menuItems: Highcharts.defaultOptions.exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems.concat([{
          text: 'custom-text',
          onclick: function() {
             // custom callback
          }
        }])
      }
    }
  },
```

example with json downloading: http://jsfiddle.net/wLergka5/

Comment: Broken example.

Answer (score 2):

You can add this

```
<script src="http://highcharts.github.io/export-csv/export-csv.js"></script>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5qdts3r3/)